# Angularjs routes are coming upto localhost only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, wamp

I have to setup a wordpress site which was developed by another team locally. They used angularjs. I am very new to angular. I placed the wordpress files in wamp server. The name of the folder is playbook.

When I tried to access the site by using url localhost/playbook, I got a javascript error saying localhost/home not found.

I checked the javascript file and I saw routing like this

```
.when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/home'
        })
```

When I added /playbook at the start like below of templateUrl, page displayed

```
.when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/playbook/home'
        })
```

Why is this happening. Shouldn't the route take the path up to localhost/playbook?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the extension `.html` for the template.Assuming your file is called `home.html`, replace your current code with

```
.when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/playbook/home.html'
        })
```

Regarding the usage of a more specific path.Consider this, you are coding a multi-module app in Angular.To seperate concerns, you may have a file structure that is based on each module.So my routes could look something like this. For my file, this was defined in app.js , which was inside the JS folder in my whole application.Additionally, you may choose to define routes in a seperate folder altogether. There is no reason for it to default to a particular file or folder.

```
foodApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',
          {
        templateUrl:'js/apps/choiceScreen/choice.html',
        controller:'choiceCtrl'

    })
    .when('/cafe',
         {
        templateUrl:'js/apps/cafe/cafeScreen.html',
        controller:'cafeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/showCafe/',
         {
        templateUrl:'js/apps/eachScreen/itemView.html',
        controller:'itemCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

Comment: No, The page is loading fine now. If add the name of route folder in the url , it is coming. My question is, why is it not taking up route folder by default? It is taking only up to localhost

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of why it's necessary to be specific about the route.Additionally, I'm not sure how your application worked without specifying the `.html` extension. Let me know if you still are unclear.

Comment: It's not a front end application. It's a wordpress site. In other words it's a php site. .htaccess is configured to accept routes without index.php in the url. That's why the routes work without adding .html.

Comment: If it's a WP site, check the WP Config file for where the website starts off, the base-url that is.